# How to color cell in APEX 5 Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex-5

I work in APEX 5 on some selling application and have Interactive Report displaying monthly review. It displays selling of some articles by days.

[image]

The source of this report is select from one table but columns of daily sale I get from function called from select clause.

```
select s.art_id, s.art_name
       , f_daily_sale('01', :GLOBAL_MONTH, :GLOBAL_YEAR, s.art_id, 1) d_01
       , f_daily_sale('02', :GLOBAL_MONTH, :GLOBAL_YEAR, s.art_id, 1) d_02
       , f_daily_sale('03', :GLOBAL_MONTH, :GLOBAL_YEAR, s.art_id, 1) d_03
       . . .
       , f_daily_sale('31', :GLOBAL_MONTH, :GLOBAL_YEAR, s.art_id, 1) d_31
from sale s
where s.month = :GLOBAL_MONTH and s.year = :GLOBAL_YEAR
group by s.art_id, s.art_name;
```

What I need is to color columns that belong to Sunday, i.e. to red. And I want  every daily cell to be clickable, to be a link to a modal page where I would display details.
How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On columns you can change type to link to open modal page with detail.

I hope this help:

```
with dts as (
  select date'2017-01-01'+rownum-1 dt from dual
  connect by level <= 366
) 
  select DT, 'data-style="background-color:red"' from dts
  where  to_char(dt, 'fmday', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN') = 'sunday';
```

This query return all sundays (date format) in 2017 with related css style for red cell.

Comment: Yes, it could be done this way. I thought that I could do this using anchor tags in select statement passing day number to next page. I am gonna try. It's only left to color Sundays.